# Integration of Interpolated function take an unacceptable amount of time

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics, interpolation

I have a simple integration which, when using an interpolation function, is taking too long to calculate:

```
c = 2.99792*10^5;
A = 3.87624*10^-14;
FreeElectronFractionData = {{3000, 1.0829044}, {2984.9246, 1.0828562}, {2969.8493, 1.0828473}, {2954.7739, 1.0828366}, {2939.6985, 1.0828238}, {2924.6231, 1.0828083}, {2909.5478, 1.0827898}, {2894.4724, 1.0827674}, 
    {2879.397, 1.0827404}, {2864.3217, 1.0827077}, {2849.2463, 1.0826683}, {2834.1709, 1.0826207}, {2819.0955, 1.0825632}, {2804.0202, 1.0824939}, {2788.9448, 1.0824106}, {2773.8694, 1.0823111}, {2758.7941, 1.0821927}, 
    {2743.7187, 1.0820531}, {2728.6433, 1.08189}, {2713.5679, 1.0817016}, {2698.4926, 1.0814865}, {2683.4172, 1.0812441}, {2668.3418, 1.0809745}, {2653.2664, 1.0806783}, {2638.1911, 1.0803569}, {2623.1157, 1.0800119}, 
    {2608.0403, 1.0796454}, {2592.965, 1.0792594}, {2577.8896, 1.0788561}, {2562.8142, 1.0784377}, {2547.7388, 1.0780061}, {2532.6635, 1.0775631}, {2517.5881, 1.0771101}, {2502.5127, 1.0766486}, {2487.4374, 1.0761797}, 
    {2472.362, 1.0757042}, {2457.2866, 1.0752228}, {2442.2112, 1.074736}, {2427.1359, 1.0742441}, {2412.0605, 1.0737472}, {2396.9851, 1.0732455}, {2381.9098, 1.0727387}, {2366.8344, 1.0722267}, {2351.759, 1.0717092}, 
    {2336.6836, 1.0711857}, {2321.6083, 1.070656}, {2306.5329, 1.0701194}, {2291.4575, 1.0695754}, {2276.3822, 1.0690234}, {2261.3068, 1.0684627}, {2246.2314, 1.0678928}, {2231.156, 1.0673129}, {2216.0807, 1.0667222}, 
    {2201.0053, 1.06612}, {2185.9299, 1.0655055}, {2170.8545, 1.064878}, {2155.7792, 1.0642365}, {2140.7038, 1.0635802}, {2125.6284, 1.0629083}, {2110.5531, 1.0622197}, {2095.4777, 1.0615136}, {2080.4023, 1.060789}, 
    {2065.3269, 1.0600449}, {2050.2516, 1.0592803}, {2035.1762, 1.0584941}, {2020.1008, 1.0576853}, {2005.0255, 1.0568526}, {1989.9501, 1.0559951}, {1974.8747, 1.0551114}, {1959.7993, 1.0542004}, {1944.724, 1.0532609}, 
    {1929.6486, 1.0522915}, {1914.5732, 1.051291}, {1899.4979, 1.0502581}, {1884.4225, 1.0491914}, {1869.3471, 1.0480894}, {1854.2717, 1.0469509}, {1839.1964, 1.0457743}, {1824.121, 1.044558}, {1809.0456, 1.0433006}, 
    {1793.9703, 1.0420003}, {1778.8949, 1.0406552}, {1763.8195, 1.0392634}, {1748.7441, 1.0378224}, {1733.6688, 1.0363292}, {1718.5934, 1.0347802}, {1703.518, 1.0331707}, {1688.4426, 1.0314941}, {1673.3673, 1.0297415}, 
    {1658.2919, 1.0279002}, {1643.2165, 1.025952}, {1628.1412, 1.0238707}, {1613.0658, 1.0216182}, {1597.9904, 1.0191391}, {1582.915, 1.0163525}, {1567.8397, 1.0131417}, {1552.7643, 1.0093401}, {1537.6889, 1.0047152}, 
    {1522.6136, 0.99895508}, {1507.5382, 0.99166793}, {1492.4628, 0.9824059}, {1477.3874, 0.97072308}, {1462.3121, 0.95625418}, {1447.2367, 0.93878259}, {1432.1613, 0.91826926}, {1417.086, 0.89483803}, 
    {1402.0106, 0.86873404}, {1386.9352, 0.84027554}, {1371.8598, 0.80981198}, {1356.7845, 0.77769325}, {1341.7091, 0.74424993}, {1326.6337, 0.70978283}, {1311.5584, 0.67455941}, {1296.483, 0.63881506}, 
    {1281.4076, 0.60275746}, {1266.3322, 0.56657254}, {1251.2569, 0.53043096}, {1236.1815, 0.4944942}, {1221.1061, 0.45891987}, {1206.0307, 0.4238656}, {1190.9554, 0.3894916}, {1175.88, 0.35596148}, {1160.8046, 0.32344154}, 
    {1145.7293, 0.29209849}, {1130.6539, 0.26209576}, {1115.5785, 0.23358875}, {1100.5031, 0.20671934}, {1085.4278, 0.18161021}, {1070.3524, 0.1583594}, {1055.277, 0.1370358}, {1040.2017, 0.11767584}, 
    {1025.1263, 0.10028183}, {1010.0509, 0.084822106}, {994.97554, 0.07123293}, {979.90017, 0.05942197}, {964.8248, 0.049273035}, {949.74943, 0.040651617}, {934.67406, 0.033410795}, {919.59868, 0.027397081}, 
    {904.52331, 0.022455872}, {889.44794, 0.018436284}, {874.37257, 0.015195242}, {859.2972, 0.012600771}, {844.22182, 0.01053444}, {829.14645, 0.008892887}, {814.07108, 0.007588385}, {798.99571, 0.006548454}, 
    {783.92034, 0.005714659}, {768.84496, 0.005040865}, {753.76959, 0.004491226}, {738.69422, 0.004038206}, {723.61885, 0.003660784}, {708.54348, 0.003342951}, {693.46811, 0.003072499}, {678.39273, 0.002840079}, 
    {663.31736, 0.002638491}, {648.24199, 0.002462145}, {633.16662, 0.002306669}, {618.09125, 0.00216861}, {603.01587, 0.002045214}, {587.9405, 0.00193427}, {572.86513, 0.001833981}, {557.78976, 0.001742876}, 
    {542.71439, 0.00165974}, {527.63902, 0.001583562}, {512.56364, 0.001513494}, {497.48827, 0.001448819}, {482.4129, 0.001388928}, {467.33753, 0.001333298}, {452.26216, 0.00128148}, {437.18678, 0.001233084}, 
    {422.11141, 0.00118777}, {407.03604, 0.001145243}, {391.96067, 0.00110524}, {376.8853, 0.001067531}, {361.80992, 0.001031911}, {346.73455, 0.000998196}, {331.65918, 0.000966223}, {316.58381, 0.000935844}, 
    {301.50844, 0.000906924}, {286.43307, 0.00087934}, {271.35769, 0.00085298}, {256.28232, 0.00082774}, {241.20695, 0.000803522}, {226.13158, 0.000780232}, {211.05621, 0.000757781}, {195.98083, 0.00073608}, 
    {180.90546, 0.000715041}, {165.83009, 0.00069457}, {150.75472, 0.00067457}, {135.67935, 0.000654928}, {120.60397, 0.000635516}, {105.5286, 0.000616174}, {90.453231, 0.000596693}, {75.377859, 0.000576785}, 
    {60.302487, 0.000556011}, {45.227116, 0.000533637}, {30.151744, 0.000508209}, {15.076372, 0.000475883}, {0, 0.000410148}}; 

FreeElectronFraction := Interpolation[FreeElectronFractionData, InterpolationOrder -> 1]

ElectronNumberDensity[\[Eta]_] := (redShift = 6.64*^18^2/((c - Sqrt[c]*Sqrt[c - 2.*A*\[Eta]])/A)^2 - 1.; FreeElectronFraction[redShift]*1.42*^-7*(1. + redShift)^3)

Plot[NIntegrate[ElectronNumberDensity[eta], {eta, \[Eta], 3.78*^18}, MaxRecursion -> 15], {\[Eta], 1.47*^17, 2.66*^17}]

ListPlot[FreeElectronFractionData]
```

The 25 seconds doesn't seem to be a lot, but this calculation is inside another integral which didn't complete in eight hours.  As nearly as I can tell, this integral is the culprit.  Specifically the interpolation function.

I've seen other suggested solutions on this board, but none of them worked for me.  One of the solutions looked promising: creating a pure function based on the interpolated data and using that in the integral, but that is beyond my skills.

Comment: You could try turning off symbolic processing and reduce the MaxRecursion `NIntegrate[ElectronNumberDensity[eta], {eta, \[Eta], 3.78*^18}, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, MaxRecursion -> 2]`.

Comment: Sorry, but reducing the MaxRecursion appears to introduce unacceptable inaccuracies to the integral results.  The 'SymbolicProcessing' did seem to have a positive effect on performance, though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code in the question takes about 40 seconds on my computer.  Turning off `SymbolicProcessing`, as suggested by Tim Laska in a comment, reduces the run time to about 16 seconds.  Although reducing `MaxRecursion` further reduces the run time, it also generates error messages that the integration is not converging to sufficient accuracy.  (Whether this matters from a practical point of view depends on how the results will be used.)

Instead, let us take advantage of the fact that `NIntegrate` in `Plot` repeatedly performs the same integral over the range `{2.66*^17, 3.78*^18}` to break the integral into two pieces.

```
int = NIntegrate[ElectronNumberDensity[eta], {eta, 2.66*^17, 3.78*^18}]
Plot[int + NIntegrate[ElectronNumberDensity[eta], {eta, η, 2.66*^17}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], {η, 1.47*^17, 2.66*^17}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

which produces the desired plot in under 5 seconds.

[image]

The plot agrees well with that produced by the code in the question.

**Addendum**

Even faster is to use `NDSolveValue` instead of `NIntegrate`.

```
NDSolveValue[{g'[eta] == -ElectronNumberDensity[eta], g[2.66*^17] == int}, 
    g, {eta, 1.47*^17, 2.66*^17}]
Plot[%[η], {η, 1.47*^17, 2.66*^17}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

which produces the same curve in less than a second.

Comment: This looks promising, but I'm unfamiliar with the workings of ODE solving.  Why, for instance, do you take $g'[\eta] == -ElectronNumberDensity[\eta]$ for the first equation?

Comment: @Quarkly  Basically, we are applying the fundamental theorem of calculus, that a differential is the inverse of an integral.  Solving the differential equation, therefore, gives the integral, if boundary conditions are chosen properly.  The minus sign arises, because `η` is the lower bound of the original integral, rather than the upper bound.  Using `NDSolve` is much more efficient than using `NIntegrate`, when one endpoint of the integral is a variable.  This can be seen by understanding that both functions in effect sum a set of finite elements, but only `NDSolve` returns a running total.

Comment: Can you tell me how you picked the lower and upper limits on the first NIntegrate function?  Why did you pick the upper boundary of the Plot function call (2.66*^17) as the lower limit of the NIntegrate function?  The boundary of the Plot is arbitrary.

Comment: I chose the upper bound of the `Plot` as the lower bound for computing `int, because doing so avoided recomputing the same quantity again and again.  However, I did this before considering the `NDSolve` approach.  I could just as well set `int == 0` and solved the ODE all the way to `3.78*^18`, which is not noticeably slower..

Comment: Plot wasn't the end product.  It was really just there to illustrate the problem.  This integral `NIntegrate[ElectronNumberDensity[etaPrime], {etaPrime, eta, constant}` is part of a larger integral.  That is, I need a general purpose solution where `eta` can be a parameter.  Any ideas?

Comment: Use `intg = NDSolveValue[{g'[etaprime] == -ElectronNumberDensity[etaprime], g[const2] == g2}, {etaprime,const1,const2}]`, where `const1` is the smallest value of `eta` in which you are interested, and `const2` is the largest value in which you are interested.  Of course, you need to know `g2`, the value of the integral at `const2`.  If the integrand becomes small beyond `const2`, you can set `g2 == 0`.  `intg` then is the integral you want as an `InterpolationFunction`, and you can use `intg[eta]` however you wish.  For instance, `Plot[intg[eta], {eta, const1, const2}]`.

Answer (score 8):

This

```
c = 2.99792*10^5;
A = 3.87624*10^-14;
FreeElectronFractionData = {...YourData...}; 
Clear[\[Eta]]; (* just in case there was a prior assignment to Eta *)
redShift = 6.64*^18^2/((c - Sqrt[c]*Sqrt[c - 2.*A*\[Eta]])/A)^2 - 1.;
FreeElectronFraction = Interpolation[FreeElectronFractionData, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
ElectronNumberDensity[\[Eta]_] := FreeElectronFraction[redShift ]*1.42*^-7*(1. +redShift^3);
Plot[NIntegrate[ElectronNumberDensity[eta], {eta, \[Eta], 3.78*^18}, MaxRecursion -> 15], {\[Eta], 1.47*^17, 2.66*^17}]
ListPlot[FreeElectronFractionData]
```

completes in a less than ten seconds, mostly I believe because I changed

```
FreeElectronFraction := Interpolation[...]
```

to

```
FreeElectronFraction = Interpolation[...]
```

which means the calculation of the interpolating function will be done only once and the result will then be repeatedly used instead of calculating the interpolation function thousands of times.

I also moved the location of your calculation of `redShift` which may or may not have been necessary, but I was getting recursion errors and fixed those by moving the `redShift` calculation.

Please check all this very carefully to make certain the result is correct.

Comment: Your `\[Eta]` might not being used properly. You should probably turn `redShift` into a function of `\[Eta]` and use that in `ElectronNumberDensity`. That way there's no question the order of operations is right.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I was trying to do the minimum number of changes to his code, but you make an excellent point. If the original poster tests this carefully then I would hope that he would uncover errors. If my changes are incorrect then as suggested try `redShift[\[Eta]_]:= 6.64*^18^2/((c-Sqrt[c]*Sqrt[c-2.*A*\[Eta]])/A)^2-1.;` and turn the two uses of `redShift` into `redShift[\[Eta]]` and see if this corrects the problem. Thank  you

Comment: The change in your comment indeed corrects the problem, but it also  eliminates much of the run time savings from your answer.

Comment: Redshift is a function of conformal time (eta).  Evaluating it once give the wrong answer.  However, I'm surprised that this simple calculation causes such an impact on timing.

Comment: @Quarkly the issue was that you used `:=` for the interpolation. That causes the interpolation to be re-evaluated hundreds or thousands of time. Just create the interpolating function once.

Comment: I agree.  I've incorporated it and it definitely helped.  The function resolved in an hour instead of $Aborting out after 8 hours.  Still, I think the right answer here is solving the ODE.  I'm working on integrating that change now.